# Which version does support Windows.Graphics.Capture?

Tags: windows-runtime, screen, capture

I saw the graph capture item in microsoft website is supported on 1803, but I can't run on this version.
If I call  the following code, then crashes

```
auto interop_factory = winrt::get_activation_factory<winrt::Windows::Graphics::Capture::GraphicsCaptureItem, IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GraphicsCaptureItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscaptureitem) exists indeed in Windows 10, version 1803. However, `IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop` does not, you need Windows 10, version 1903 to consume the API this way.

In Windows 10, version 1803 you are supposed to use [`GraphicsCapturePicker.PickSingleItemAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.capture.graphicscapturepicker.picksingleitemasync) instead.

Comment: How would I replace `IGraphicsCaptureItemInterop` by `GraphicsCapturePicker`. I'm having the same issue as the OP, and I'm a noob at C++, so I have no idea on how to implement that.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/robmikh/Win32CaptureSample/blob/5d6821dcebef55ee448484fe7101200a253672ce/Win32CaptureSample/App.cpp#L97) code fragment should give some idea how `PickSingleItemAsync` can be used instead of interop (you can also just clone the entire app and step through with debugger).